# Control path to pinned application to taskbar with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

How control path to pinned application to taskbar with Qt

Comment: Please don't post an answer in your question. If you want to share your solution submit it as a dedicated answer.

Comment: First, ask a question then answer it yourself and check the green checkmark of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I myself have been searching with a lot of effort for a way to customize the program path to an application pinned to the taskbar, I wanted to post here my solution related to Qt.

Problem was, that I link the starter in a set of programs (starter/updater, main) when pinning the main program.

EventFilterPinnable.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QAbstractNativeEventFilter>

#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <propsys.h>
#include <propkey.h>
#include <propvarutil.h>

HRESULT PropertyStoreSetStringValue(IPropertyStore* propertyStore, REFPROPERTYKEY pkey, PCWSTR value)
{
    PROPVARIANT propVariant;
    HRESULT hr = InitPropVariantFromString(value, &propVariant);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = propertyStore->SetValue(pkey, propVariant);
        PropVariantClear(&propVariant);
    }
    return hr;
}

HRESULT MakeWindowPinnable(HWND hwnd, PCWSTR userModelId, PCWSTR relaunchCommand, PCWSTR relaunchDisplayName, PCWSTR relaunchIcon = NULL)
{
    IPropertyStore* propertyStore;
    HRESULT hr = SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow(hwnd, IID_PPV_ARGS(&propertyStore));
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        PropertyStoreSetStringValue(propertyStore, PKEY_AppUserModel_ID, userModelId);
        PropertyStoreSetStringValue(propertyStore, PKEY_AppUserModel_RelaunchCommand, relaunchCommand);
        PropertyStoreSetStringValue(propertyStore, PKEY_AppUserModel_RelaunchDisplayNameResource, relaunchDisplayName);

        if(relaunchIcon != NULL)
        {
            PropertyStoreSetStringValue(propertyStore, PKEY_AppUserModel_RelaunchIconResource, relaunchIcon);
        }

        propertyStore->Release();
    }
    return hr;
}

void OnCreate(HWND hwnd)
{
    std::wstring sAppId = L"unique.app.id";
    std::wstring sAppRelaunchCommand = L"\"C:\\Program Files\\Path with spaces\\Starter.exe\" -a argument1";
    std::wstring sAppRelaunchDisplayName = L"Name of progam";
    std::wstring sAppRelaunchIcon = L"\"C:\\Program Files\\Path with spaces\\Icon.ico\"";

    MakeWindowPinnable(hwnd, sAppId.c_str(), sAppRelaunchCommand.c_str(), sAppRelaunchDisplayName.c_str(), sAppRelaunchIcon.c_str());
}


class EventFilterPinnable : public QAbstractNativeEventFilter
{
public:
    EventFilterPinnable() {}

    bool nativeEventFilter(const QByteArray& eventType, void* message, long* /*res*/) override
    {
        if(eventType == "windows_generic_MSG") {
            MSG* msg = static_cast<MSG*>(message);
            HWND hwnd = msg->hwnd;

            if (msg->message==WM_CREATE)
            {
                OnCreate(hwnd);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

in main.cpp simply add

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);    
app.installNativeEventFilter(new EventFilterPinnable());
....
app.exec();
```

Comment: but what(tf) is that `switch(msg->message) {
                HANDLE_MSG(hwnd, WM_CREATE, OnCreate);
            }  `  ?

Comment: you can also put more message switches if you need ... but I only need to handle WM_CREATE

#define HANDLE_MSG(hwnd, message, fn)    \
    case (message): return HANDLE_##message((hwnd), (wParam), (lParam), (fn))

Comment: but you have other messages

Comment: what's purpose of `return TRUE;` in handler? see . It's really bad approach

Comment: and i still do not see what's `HANDLE_WM_CREATE`

Comment: show into #include <windowsx.h>

but to end the subject, I have changed everything objected.

Comment: The Microsoft example says you should also handle WM_DESTROY and remove all the properties added to avoid a leak.
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/main/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appshellintegration/AppUserModelIDWindowProperty/AppUserModelIDWindowProperty.cpp

However, this probably doesn't matter if the application only has one top-level window and ends when it is closed as the OS will clean that up anyway.